# Finding a common char between two strings recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Im trying to write a recursive code that recieves 2 strings and returns True is they have a common char or False if the dont.
I first wrote an iterative code cause I thaught it may help.
The problem that I have is that I dont know how to compare all of the chars in each string. this is what i did so far:
iterative code:

```
def any_char_present_it(s1,s2):
    if len(s1)==0 or len(s2)==0:
        return False
    for i in s2:
        for m in s1:
            if i==m:
                return True
    return False
```

recursive code:

```
def any_char_present(s1,s2):
    if len_rec(s2)==0:
        return False
    if s1[0]==s2[0]:
        return True
    return any_char_present(s1,s2[1:])
```

Comment: In case this is for homework, or specifically learning programming for the first time, I won't give the exact code I would personally use for this problem. I will give you a hint, though: You can just use sets and check the intersection. *Edit:* Oops, I see someone has already provided a set-based answer while I was writing this. Oh well.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Python language has a lot of overhead to create a recursive call stack, so you'll notice your iterative version is significantly faster with large inputs. It'll certainly be faster if you reduce the strings with sets before you recurse, especially if you limit yourself to the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets and set theory to check for common characters without iterating through everything yourself.

`has_common_chars` turns both strings into sets and finds the intersection of them.  If the length of the intersection is greater than zero, there is at least one character in common.

```
s1 = "No one writes to the Colonel"
s2 = "Now is the time or all good men to come to the ade of the lemon."
s3 = "ZZZZ"

def has_common_chars(s1, s2):
    return len(set(s1) & set(s2)) > 0

print has_common_chars(s1, s2)
print has_common_chars(s2, s3)

>>> True
>>> False
```

EDIT s/union/intersection

Comment: & is Intersection, | is Union

Comment: I should really read these things over a second time before submitting. Thanks.

Comment: Except this isn't recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Just to go off your code, you have to try every combination.  In order to do that you can decrement each string at the return statement as so:

```
#return check(s1, decremented s2) or check(decremented s1, s2)
return (any_char_present(s1,s2[1:]) or any_char_present(s1[1:],s2))
```

This should exhaust all possible combinations to find a char match at any point across the two string inputs.

Entire code:

```
def any_char_present(s1,s2):
    #update this if statement to check both strings
    #you can check for empty strings this way too
    if not s1 or not s2:
        return False
    if s1[0]==s2[0]:
        return True
    return (any_char_present(s1,s2[1:]) or any_char_present(s1[1:],s2))

print(any_char_present("xyz", "aycd"))
```

Comment: `bool(string)` returns False if string == '', else True, so instead of using *len* you can just check `if not s1 or not s2:`, or more simply `if not (s1 and s2):` in your first conditional